# Powershell Set-Item returns Object reference not set to an object of an instance

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0, powershell-5.0

I'm running the following commands in a script:

```
$currentSite = Get-Item IIS:\Sites\$WebSiteName
$currentSite.id = $WebSiteID
$currentSite | Set-Item
```

where I want to set the id for a website.
This script works on some environments and doesn't on others (looking for what's different hoping to post it soon).

Where it doesn't work it returns the following error:

```
Set-Item : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
    + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Set-Item], NullReferenceException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : path,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetItemCommand
```

So, looking for a workaround I tried the following code:

```
$currentSite = Get-Item IIS:\Sites\$WebSiteName
$currentSite | Set-Item
```

But I get the same error.

So I wonder if there are some parameters that the Set-Item needs but the Get-Item doesn't return when it works with Sites (I specified sites because I'm using the same structure setting an Application pool and I don't get any problem)

Comment: What does `$currentSite | gm` return when you get the error?

Comment: `TypeName: System.Object` do you need the list as well?

Comment: Try `if ($currentSite -ne $null)  { Write-Host currentSite is NOT null! }` before the `Set-Item` call. From the error it seems that `path` is null or if not null, that it points to nowhere. Due to this, you should try out with the other `Set-Item` syntax, something like: `Set-Item -path IIS:\Sites\$WebSiteName -value $currentSite`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if this doesn't answer the question, I found a workaround for the problem:

Instead of use

```
$currentSite = Get-Item IIS:\Sites\$WebSiteName
$currentSite.id = $WebSiteID
$currentSite | Set-Item
```

for setting the id for a WebSite can be used the following command:

```
Set-ItemProperty -Path IIS:\Sites\$WebSiteName -Name id -Value $WebSiteID
```